# How To Send Free SMS Programmatically?

Tags: sms

Here in Brazil we have a program called [CoolSMS](http://www.cool.com.br/), that sends free SMS to all the big  operators that have here on our territory, but even for VIVO (we need to pay R$0.26 for every email-to-sms) it goes for free. Then I want to know how to do this programmatically.

*Doesn't matter the language, but I prefer Java.*

Answer (score 1):

You need to send your SMS as `email` like eg

The phone number is `11111111111`

So u send email to `11111111111@phonecompanyweb2smsgateway.com.` This is how it works in UK atleast. I am not sure abt Brazil.

And here is list of [**Gateways**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways)